# Decode a string 'BHQsZMaQQok='

Tags: c#, cryptography, tripledes

I'm trying to decode a string like '`BHQsZMaQQok=`'.

All I know about the string is that it must be a number. I can find more encrypted string if it is necessary.

Comment: do you know what type of encryption was used to encrypt it in the first place?

Comment: It looks like Base64 to me

Comment: Decodes to hex 0474 2c64 c690 4289

Comment: It is a number of type long. I don't know anything about encryption algorithm. This is what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 5):

It's a [base64](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) string, 8 bytes: 04 74 2C 64 C6 90 42 89

Interpreted as an IEEE754 [double](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html), it is 3.3121005957308838680392659232E-287

As a [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) long: 320930284789842569

As a [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) long: -8556117160291961852

One can only guess how to interpret it...

Comment: The number for this string is: 910619. I think this is a triple DES encription but can't find the secret key.

Comment: @MShevroja Finding a triple DES key is not possible without more information about the key. Brute forcing the key (at minimum testing 2^112 values, possibly 2^168 values) is not feasible.